# How to keep Navigation bar & Tab bar when using segue to show a new view

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, segue, tabbar

I want to show/have navigation bar and tab bar both when open a new view (segue with show) from tab bar item view. Please refer to below screenshot.

/ / / in the 1st scenario, when I click button in Song view, in the opened view tab bar is displayed and stay current item 1. But there is no navigation bar, and only a back button - Song, which is un-editable.
[image]

/ / / in the 2nd scenario, I embedded opened view in a navigation controller, when I click button in Song view, in the opened view tab bar is gone and navigation bar is here. So how could I keep both? In another word, is one navigation controller is enough for one control flow? like navigation controller -> VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3. Or it need to be like NC -> VC1 -> NC -> VC2.

[image]

/ / / Update as commented, but now Navigation bar & Tab bar both disappeared when opening the new view by clicking the button:(

[image]

/ / / Well, I just found an interesting thing, if I set segue to Push, which is deprecated then Xcode add a navigation bar on my VC. Even I switch the segue to as Show again. The navigation bar is still there, I don't know if it is some bugs on my Xcode, but I could have a navigation bar and tab bar together finally.

Answer (score 0):

Embed TabBarController inside Navigation Controller.

> Start-> NavigationController(rootViewController for app window) ->
>   TabBarController(rootViewController for NavigationController) ->
>   YourOtherViewControllers

It will look like this,

[image: story board screen shot]

Comment: My current start VC is "Tab Bar VC", and I select it and Editor-> embed in, but all options is gray, un-selectable... Also I try to cancel the initial property of Tab Bar VC then do the embed in again, but the option still is un-selectable. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Yea, checked you can't do it that way. First manually drag NavigationController then delete the RootViewController that comes with it. Now again drag a TabBarController. Control + Drag from navigation controller to TabBar controller and select rootViewController option.

Comment: I added an image for you to take a look.

Comment: I try your method, but navigation bar & tab bar are both gone... when opening the new view by clicking the button in item1 view.